# Remember page index in se site

Tags: bug, new-nav

I'm on page 2 of meta.stackexchange going over some questions on page 2.
When I click on a question and read it and either back out of the question using the browser back button or I click Questions link it takes me back to page 1.

Can we please have a small feature request to take me back to the page I was looking at?

[image]

Imagine if I was on any page greater than 5, this would be a nuisance.

Comment: [new-nav] problems .... I've always opened them in incognito to overcome this particular problem, *sigh*

Comment: The search and the previous navigation behave like this, so tagging as bug since there isn't a good reason for the design to be otherwise.

Comment: @braiam - thanks and yes this is not just on the new navigation.

Comment: Pixelmeow mine was posted 2 days ago.  Yours was posted 16 minutes ago.  Yours is the duplicate not mine.  Mark yours as closed based on this topic

Comment: Sorry, I posted mine on the 16th. And I used incognito, which worked until just now when it started doing the same thing again. Thanks.